# Ninja Forms - using form data after submission

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress website, in which there's a form page, based on [ninja forms](https://ninjaforms.com/) form plugin.

After a user **submit** the form, I'd like to process the input (preferably on server side) and display it right away (either by redirecting to another page, or on the same page).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is hook for this: [ninja_forms_after_submission](http://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/submission-processing-hooks/)

```
add_action( 'ninja_forms_after_submission', 'my_ninja_forms_after_submission' );
function my_ninja_forms_after_submission( $form_data ){
  // Do stuff.
}
```